# Windows 8 XAML-only solution for toggling the visibility of a control when hovering the mouse over a different control

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am working on a project and need help in finding a Windows 8 XAML-only solution for toggling the visibility of a control when hovering the mouse over a different control. The control can be a button or any Windows8 control and the code needs to be in XAML because all my logic is in XAML. 
I tried numerous XAML solutions but I guess I am missing something. In my first attempt I wrote an event trigger, but string can't be converted into visibility and so the following code crashes when executed.

Can anyone or any expert at Microsoft please help me in this. I really appreciate your help. I am looking for is a solution that does not require any code in the code-behind, it should be complete XAML code.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Margin="5" x:Name="btn1">Button 1</Button>

        <Button Margin="5" x:Name="btn2">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.GotFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btn1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Button.Visibility" To="Collapsed" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.LostFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btn1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Button.Visibility" To="Visible" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
            Button 2
        </Button>

        <Button Margin="5" x:Name="btn3">Button 3</Button>

    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not control Visibility with DoubleAnimation, since Visibility is not a double. You should use ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="btn1">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

I would also suggest using behaviors and visual states to make your XAML more designer friendly.

Comment: Denis, Thanks.. Can you please write the whole XAML as I am not sure where to put the code snippet you shared?

Comment: Simply replace <DoubleAnimation ... /> in your code with my code and update Visibility to Visible for LostFocus trigger.

Comment: My code doesn't compile as there are no event triggers in WinRT XAML. I just out it there to show the logic and the code doesn't work. So only I was asking you if you can write the whole XAML. This is not WPF, it's Windows8 XAML

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to flip the `Visibility` you can just use a Binding to the `IsPointerOver` property:

```
<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Margin="5" x:Name="btn1">Button 1</Button>

    <Button Margin="5" x:Name="btn2"  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=btn1, Path=IsPointerOver, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        Button 2
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

You'll need to add the code for the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` since that's not built in like it is in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can use EventTrigger with RoutedEvent.May be it would be usefull

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TagAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border x:Name="AppButton" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="tbName" />
                      </Storyboard>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="tbName" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>

                </VisualStateGroup>



              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <Grid Width="100">
                <Rectangle Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="Transparent"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Button 2" x:Name="tbName" />

              </Grid>
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid>
  <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Margin="5" x:Name="btn1" Content="Button 1" />
    <Button Margin="5" x:Name="btn2" Style="{StaticResource TagAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Margin="5" x:Name="btn3" Content="Button 3" />

  </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

[WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

This has many builtin converters in the framework, including the BooleanToVisibilityConverter.